# Search and print a line in every file in directory using glob.glob

Tags: python, canopy

I have a folder on my desktop with 200+ txt files.  I want to print line number 1050.539  in every file. Here is what I have:

```
import glob
f=glob.glob('/Users/me/Desktop/Final/matched/ipmatches/*.txt')
for line in f:
    if '1050.539' in line:
        print line
```

Comment: does what you have work?

Answer (score 3):

Glob only returns a list of file paths, you still have to open the files and read them.

```
import glob
filesList = glob.glob('/Users/me/Desktop/Final/matched/ipmatches/*.txt')

for fileName in filesList:
    with open(fileName, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if '1050.539' in line:
                print(line)
```